# Why do packages have both individual esm, cjs and type files for their submodules as well as main, modules and typings in the root package.json?

Tags: npm, package.json

[react-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap) root package.json: -

```
{
   ...
   "main": "cjs/index.js",
   "module": "esm/index.js",
   "types": "esm/index.d.ts",
   ...
}
```

And it's Accordion submodule: -

```
{
   "name": "react-bootstrap/Accordion",
   "private": true,
   "main": "../cjs/Accordion.js",
   "module": "../esm/Accordion.js",
   "types": "../esm/Accordion.d.ts"
}
```

Likewise for [@mui/material](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/material)...

Root package.json: -

```
{
   ...
   "main": "./node/index.js",
   "module": "./index.js",
   "types": "./index.d.ts",
   ...
}
```

Accordion component/submodule: -

```
{
   "sideEffects": false,
   "module": "./index.js",
   "main": "../node/Accordion/index.js",
   "types": "./index.d.ts"
}
```

Slightly different directory structures/syntax but they amount to the same thing - although they have subfolders for each component that contains full ESM, CJS and types and they also have compiled files for these which are pointed to through the main, modules and typings fields in the root package.json.

Why is this? Does this not amount to duplicate code?